# Find the value(s) of $a$ such that the given vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Considering the vectors $x=[1,1,-1]$, $y=[2,a+1,-1]$, $z=[1,0,-a]$

Find the conditions on a that ensures that

span$(x, y, z)$ = $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: What have you tried? How would you normally tell whether three vectors span $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I have tried row reducing, using the concept of linear combinations

Answer (score 2):

You just have to make sure that the three vectors $x,y,z$ are indipendent.

There are several ways to do that, maybe the simpler one is just to impose that:
$$\det{\begin{vmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & a+1 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & -a \end{vmatrix}} \neq 0$$